# Is there a way to cancel the fighting "mode" that you get stuck in when in a fight and try to fly away?

Tags: dc-universe-online

When I get into a fight in DC Universe Online, and I see my health getting low I attempt to fly away but my characters is stuck in a hover state when I a getting hit and trying to leave. Is there a way to stop my character from just hovering when I am trying to fly.

If you are confused do this... activate flight then use a melee attack or blast and then immediately try to fly after that, your character will hover before actually going into a full blown fly.

Answer (score 3):

In combat your movement abilities will be limited, they will also be limited when you are attacked while using movement ability. Same goes when you attack in the movement mode.

It seems there's a fixed amount of time (I'm not sure how long it is - maybe 3 seconds or 5 seconds?) that you'll have to stay out of combat before you can move at full speed again.

But I think there are some movement skills that you can learn and use to get out of or get in to combat really fast.

Answer (score 0):

It is an intended function, mostly for PvP reasons, that you are slowed after you cast a power, use your weapon, or are hit.  After a few seconds, if nothing else slows you, you'll regain your full speed.

With Aerial movement, there is a way around this.  Swoop Attack will allow you to resume your speed immediately:

Not certain, but I believe:

- with Agile movement, Grapple Line can still be used while slowed.
- with Swift movement, Inertial Flywheel can still be used while
  slowed.